# Micronaut: How do I map all the properties values in HashMap?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, microservices, micronaut

I have been learning micronaut for sake of learning and for a small scale project and I have been stuck on a problem.

So assume I have this data in **application.yml** file

```
output:
    -file:
        name: PDF
        size: 50000
    -file:
        name: DOCX
        size: 35000
```

So my goal was to map this exact data in HashMap which I can use further. I want my code to have all the data independent of any condition. If I add another file type it should automatically map data for that too.
So in a nutshell at the end I want to have a **Map<name, path>** with all the values available in yaml.
I tried with EachProperty.

https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-configuration/guide/index.html#eachProperty
but I'd have to pass 'name' as argument.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add what have you tried to achieve so far? How have you configured your bean factory and what results it lead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *micronaut* `@EachProperty` allows to drive `Bean`(s) creation out of application properties, thus it will create beans (`Singleton` POJOs) with properties derived from the nested configuration key / values.

An **important note** to take into consideration when using `@EachProperty` configuration is that **it only binds to a top level configuration key** i.e. and that the created beans will be named after the nested **top higher** property which then should be unique.

Your configuration then won't work unless changed to the following:

```yaml
output:
  # Below config will drive a bean named "pdf", more details below
  pdf:
    size: 50000
  # Below config will drive a bean named "docx"
  docx:
    size: 35000
```

Note that in above configuration, the `name` attribute is omitted as it can be derived from the bean configured name itself:

```java
@EachProperty(value = "output")
public class FileType {

    private String name;

    private int size;

    public FileType(@Parameter("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FileType{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", size=" + size +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The `FileType` constructor will have the configured bean name (derived from the configuration key) injected and the above type will produce two bean at application runtime:

> FileType{name='pdf', size=50000}
> FileType{name='docx', size=35000}

As those beans are already handled by the *micronaut* core container, you can have them injected into any other bean.

Otherwise, if you wish to have your beans mapped to a particular configuration format such as a `Map [NAME -> SIZE]`, you can:

1. Create another `Singleton` bean as a configuration wrapper
2. Inject the `FileType` beans
3. Map the injected `FileType` beans to your custom format
4. Make this custom format accessible your configuration wrapper

Here down a sample configuration wrapper:

```java
@Singleton
public class FileTypeConfiguration {

    private final Map<String, Integer> fileTypes;

    @Inject
    public FileTypeConfiguration(List<FileType> fileTypes) {
        this.fileTypes = fileTypes.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(FileType::getName, FileType::getSize)
                );
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getFileTypes() {
        return fileTypes;
    }
}
```

where you have your configuration accessed through `FileTypeConfiguration#getFileTypes` (`FileTypeConfiguration` must be `@Inject`ed or accessed through `ApplicationContext`).

Comment: EachProperty can also work with lists (`@EachProperty(list = true)`), just FYI

Comment: Thanks @tmarwen, saved the day. All looks good, works well in my project. Although I didnt get why did add inject on FileTypeConfiguration constructor. I am not sure whats the purpose there, maybe I am totally unaware of this concept.
Thanks James for your input as well.

Comment: @JamesKleeh thanks for the extra insight. I am already aware of that property feature but since it may lead confusion to the post subject I omitted mentioning it.
@RobinSingh, you can omit it since *micronaut* will automatically wire your dependencies (the `FileType` beans) and its simply a matter of preference (I always prefer to have it clear for the reader that this `constructor` is an injection point). You are welcome and glad to help.