# How to read a mapping as a map in Micronaut

Tags: java, configuration, yaml, hashmap, micronaut

I am working on a application based on Micronaut 2.5.13. I have a requirement when I have to a keep a mapping a string value to another string value, so that I can replace it in my app logic.

I have created properties in `application.yaml` like this

```
myapp:
  mapping:
  enabled: true
  mappings:
    a: b
    c: d
```

I want to read the mappings values as a Map in my Service class which looks like this:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Value;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Map;

@Context
public class MappingService {

    private final boolean mappingEnabled;
    private final Map<String, String> mappings;

    public MappingService(
            @Value("${myapp.mapping.enabled}") boolean mappingEnabled,
            @Value("${myapp.mapping.mappings}") Map<String, String> mappings
    ) {
        this.mappingEnabled = mappingEnabled;
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public String mapValue(String key) {
        if (mappingEnabled) {
            return mappings.getOrDefault(key, key); // If key not found, return the original key
        } else {
            return key; // Mapping is disabled, return the original key
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run the above code, getting below error:

```
 Error resolving property value [${myapp.mapping.mappings}]. Property doesn't exist
```

Seems like Micronaut is not able to identify Map type property in yaml. App is successfully reading the other property `myapp.mapping.enabled` which is of boolean type.

Any Suggestion on this ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In micronaut you can use `@EachProperty` annotation to map a set of properties into a `List`

In this case maybe you could create a Bean called `GatewayString` and use `@EachProperty`

```
@EachProperty("myapp.mapping.mappings")
public class GatewayString{
    private String from;
    private String to;

   public String getFrom() {
    return from;
   }

   public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
   }

   public String getTo() {
    return to;
   }

   public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
   }
}
```

And then in your service you can use it

```
@Singleton
public class MappingService {
   private final boolean mappingEnabled;
   private final List<GatewayString> mappings;

   public MappingService(
        @Value("${myapp.mapping.enabled}") boolean mappingEnabled,
        List<GatewayString> mappings
   ) {
    this.mappingEnabled = mappingEnabled;
    this.mappings = mappings;
   }

   public String mapValue(String key) {
    if (mappingEnabled) {
        return mappings.stream()
            .filter(mapperString ->mapperString.getFrom().equals(key))
            .map(MapperString::getTo).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Key not found"));
    } else {
        return key; // Mapping is disabled, return the original key
    }
}
}
```

Also you can review this answer [Micronaut: How do I map all the properties values in HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647513/micronaut-how-do-i-map-all-the-properties-values-in-hashmap)